# Sum total of all of field A where the site code matches

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I have some existing code:

```
select
job.job_number,
job_status_log.status_code,
job_status.status_name,
central_site.site_code,
central_site.site_name,
'wc ' || to_char(trunc(job.job_entry_date, 'IW'), 'dd month')  as week_job_raised,
TO_CHAR(job.job_entry_date, 'MONTH') as month_job_raised,
'wc ' || to_char(trunc(job.actual_comp_date, 'IW'), 'dd month')  as week_job_complete,
TO_CHAR(job.actual_comp_date, 'MONTH') as month_job_complete,
job.job_entry_date as Job_Started,
job.actual_comp_date as Job_Completed,
job.job_notes,
job.job_easting,
job.job_northing,
job_attribute.param_num_value as Hours_On_Job

from
job
inner join job_status_log on job.job_number = job_status_log.job_number
inner join job_status on job_status_log.status_code = job_status.status_code
inner join central_site on job.site_code = central_site.site_code
inner join job_attribute on  job.job_number = job_attribute.job_number 

where
job_status_log.allocated_officer = 'ID51' and
job.job_log_number = job_status_log.job_log_number and
job_status_log.status_code not in ('XJOB','9990') and
job_attribute.param_type_code = 'GRFF' and
job.actual_comp_date is not null
```

which produces the following:

```
Job Number    Site_Code     Hours_On_Job
12345            23               10
12346            23                8
12347            8                 2
12348            3                 3
```

What I would like to do is find a way of adding another column to add  up all HOURS_ON_JOB values for each SITE_CODE in the report and then display it in a new column called TOTAL_HOURS_ON_SITE

```
Job Number    Site_Code     Hours_On_Job     Total_Hours_On_Site
12345            23               10                 18
12346            23                8                 18 
12347            8                 2                  2 
12348            3                 3                  3
```

Comment: Your select returns at least 10 columns, but the specified result has only 3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the column:

```
sum(job_attribute.param_num_value) over (partition by central_site.site_code) as Total_Hours_On_Site
```

that will give you the sum of the jobs partioned by site. That might be what you want according to your sample data.